# JPA: Multiple values matching multiple values

Tags: java, jpa

How to match multiple values by multiple values? (all matches)

For the following example, tags are provided, the query will return all documents with all tags matched. How to do that in JPA? Thanks.

Data:

```
Document 1 : { id: 1, name: "doc1", tags: [1, 2] }
Document 2 : { id: 2, name: "doc2", tags: [2, 3] }
Tag 1 : { id: 1, name: "tag1" }
Tag 2 : { id: 2, name: "tag2" }
Tag 3 : { id: 3, name: "tag3" }
```

Scenarios:

```
Criteria: "tag1", "tag2"
=> Return: "doc1"

Criteria: "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"
=> Return: Nothing

Criteria: "tag2"
=> Return: "doc1" and "doc2"
```

Entities:

```java
public class Document {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "DOCUMENT_TAG_RLAT")
    private List<Tag> tags;
}

public class Tag {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paulek I didn't try your solution, but I think of a solution which works.

```
select d from Document d 
where 
    (select count(t) from d.tags as t, Tag t2 where t.id = t2.id and t2 in (:tags)) 
    =
    :tagCount
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perfect solution, but this will work:

```
public List<Document> documentsByTags(List<String> tagNames) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Document> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Document.class);
    Root<Document> documents = criteriaQuery.from(Document.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    for (String tagName : tagNames) {
        Subquery<Long> sq = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<Tag> tags = sq.from(Tag.class);
        sq.select(tags.<Long>get("documents")).where(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(tags.get("name"), tagName);
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.in(documents.<Long> get("id")).value(sq));
    }
    criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

    TypedQuery<Document> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Also, in my opinion you need bidirectional relation `@ManyToMany` (don't see on your `Tag.class` property for documents maybe you just didn't paste), and in your `@JoinTable` annotation you have to specify joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns.